# Scrollview content offset unexpectedly change while change button image programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I am facing this problem last few days, I am changing the button image After getting the API response but when i change the button image programmatically it also change the content offset. Why this happen please help me.

Comment: Show us some details: code, view hierarchy, etc.

Comment: viewDidLayoutSubview calls after the uibutton image chnage.

(it always call first time when my viewcontroller load beacuse i wrote some code in it)